# Unable to record https application in VUGen (Loadrunner)

Tags: loadrunner

IE8
LR11
Protocol: HTTP/HTML
application:https

When i tried to record https:// application in VUGen (loadrunner 11) i am unable to record and get an error message "Internet Explorer cannot diplay the webpage" means not connecting to the server. Application working fine when manually open in browser, issue is only while recording.

Can someone please help me? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
KP

Answer (score 1):

Do you have proper credentials?

Do you have any conflicting software, such as antivirus running?

Are you trying to record a 64 bit browser with a 32 bit application?

You should probably grab the software requirements for your version of loadrunner and cross check your environment against the software requirements as this cross check resolves over 90% of recording issues